# Redis message queue with producer and consumer in different languages

Tags: node.js, redis, jedis

I am using Redis database for building a message queue. I am trying to push the messages to the queuse using jedis in java and trying to consume the messages using rsmq-worker in node.js. However, the messages produced are not reveived at the node.js side. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you use pub/sub or some redis data structure? What about serialization, do you use any? Use redis-cli monitor to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The languages used to read and write from Redis won't make a difference. Connect to Redis and make sure that jedis is pushing the messages as expected, and add some test data and check node.js is able to read it.